# Unable to override super class __init__(): object has no attribute '_testMethodName'?

Tags: python-2.7, class, python-unittest

Following this answer of this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753640/inheritance-and-overriding-init-in-python), I'm trying to override super class init function of testing project with python unittest that has three classes as below:

**base.py**

```
import unittest

    class BaseTest(unittest.TestCase):
        def setUp(self):
            print '\n\t Prepare configuration'
        #: executed after each test
        def tearDown(self):
            print '\n\t Closing session'
```

**helper.py**

```
from base import *

class HELPER(BaseTest):
    """ Predefine Parameter """
    URL         = ''
    ID          = ''
    Module      = ''
    def __init__(self, module=''):

        self.Module = module

    def open_url(self):
        print "INIT FROM SUPER CLASS IS "
        print self.Module
        status_code = 200
        self.assertEqual(200,status_code)
```

**test_province.py**

```
from helper import *

class TestProvince(HELPER):
    def __init__(self, module = ''):
        super(TestProvince, self).__init__()
        self.Module = 'Province'

    def test_open_url(self):
        self.open_url()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

The detail is that in `test_province.py` that I tried to override super class `HELPER`'s init function but it does not work with an error execption

```
AttributeError: 'TestProvince' object has no attribute '_testMethodName'
```

What is wrong or missing with this? How can I override super class init function correctly? Please kindly help Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The docstring for `unittest.TestCase` includes this text:

> If it is necessary to override the `__init__` method, the base class `__init__` method must always be called. It is important that subclasses should not change the signature of their `__init__` method, since instances of the classes are instantiated automatically by parts of the framework in order to be run.

So the problem is not with how `TestProvince` is inheriting from `HELPER`, but with how `HELPER` is overriding the `__init__` method it inherited from the library code. If you add a call to `super(HELPER, self).__init__`, it will probably work properly.

You probably also need to change your `__init__` to match the signature the base class uses: `__init__(self, methodName='runTest')`

A final note: Python 2 is going to be losing its official support from the Python developers at the end of the year, so you may be better served learning Python 3 now, rather than learning Python 2 and them needing to update your knowledge for the newer version. It's relevant in this context, because Python 3 lets you use `super` with no arguments, which is pretty nice (no need to repeat yourself with the current class name).

Comment: thanks very much for your helpful answer, I managed to solve problem from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27158573/how-to-delete-a-record-by-id-in-flask-sqlalchemy . Anyway I've learned something new :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would like to thank you @Blckknght very much for your useful detail answer.

I managed to find solution from this [old thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562775/deriving-a-class-from-testcase-throws-two-errors) (7 years ago), so I changed all three classes as the following:

**base.py**

```
import unittest

class BaseTest(unittest.TestCase):
    # ** Adding init Function from unittest class **
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        unittest.TestCase.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def setUp(self):
        print '\n\t Prepare configuration'
    #: executed after each test
    def tearDown(self):
        print '\n\t Closing session'
```

**helper.py**

```
from base import *

class HELPER(BaseTest):
    """ Predefine Parameter """
    URL         = ''
    ID          = ''
    Module      = ''
    # *** Adding init function from class BaseTest ***
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        BaseTest.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.controller = object()


    def open_url(self):
        print "INIT FROM SUPER CLASS IS "
        print self.Module
        status_code = 200
        self.assertEqual(200,status_code)
```

**test_province.py**

from helper import *

```
class TestProvince(HELPER):
    # *** Calling init function from class HELPER
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        HELPER.__init__(self,*args, **kwargs)
        self.Module = 'Province'

    def test_open_url(self):
        self.open_url()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

After this, I could access any variable inside super class HELPER from sub-class TestProvince.

The cause root of problem could be I might trying to inherit **init**() function of testCase of class of unittest instead of class HELPER itself. Thanks